# How to clear the form after submitting in model-driven form? (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

How can I clear the form after submitting in model-driven form? Do I have to use `ngModel`? Thanks

```
<form [ngFormModel]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" [ngFormControl]="name">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

.

```
myForm: ControlGroup;
name: AbstractControl;

ngOnInit()
{
    this.myForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        'name': [""]
    });
    this.name = this.myForm.controls['name'];
}


onSubmit() {
    this.name.value = ""; // This is not working.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the controls in `this.myForm.controls` and call `updateValue()`. Otherwise see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4933

Answer (score 3):

As of Updated angular2 version angular2 provide us `reset` functionality to reset all the controls of the form simply use this syntax.

```
this.Your_form_name.reset();
```

PS: after form submit if you reinitialize form it may clear the values once but state does't reset at all,i mean form will not in dirt state anymore (validation point of view).

for more detail refer here

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is reinitialize the form again as below:

```
this.myForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    'name': [""]
});
```

This will reset the formControlName field back to empty

Answer (score 2):

Another way useful if you have some server validation is to do this:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)">
    ...
</form>
```

and

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
onSubmit(myForm: NgForm) {
    // do something and if no error
    myForm.reset();
}
```